# Detect exact string value of scalar in regex matching

Tags: regex, perl

Say I have `$foo = "bar.baz"`

I want to use the scalar $foo to find strings that contain "bar.baz" (anywhere in the string), but not the regex-evaluted version of $foo.

So the line: `if( $other =~ m/$foo/ ) ...` 
isn't working, because $foo is being evaluated such that the '.' is evaluated to any character. How do I stop that?

Comment: $foo = "bar\\.baz"; or the more sensible $foo = 'bar\.baz';

Comment: Declare `$foo` as a regex type in the first place! `$foo = qr'bar\.baz'` or `$foo = qr'bar[.]baz'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pick one:

1. `$foo = quotemeta("bar.baz");`
2. `if ($other =~ m/\Q$foo/)`

(Both are actually the same thing, just done at different times.)

Comment: 3. if (index($other, $foo) >= 0) { ... }

Comment: Ha.  Yes; I'm long out of the habit of even considering `index` because I recall Ilya Zakharevich's tirades against it.  Eventually I discovered that he was at the time the maintainer of the regex code, and took any aspersions against its performance — such as recommendations to use `index` instead – almost as personal attacks; but the habit was too entrenched by then.