# Regex matching by scalars in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am using regular expression using scalars here. First time though. I will put the code. It should be self evident

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $regex = "PM*C";
my $var = "PM_MY_CALC";

 if($var =~ m/$regex/){
    print "match \n";
 }

 else{

    print "no match\n";
 }
```

The output that I get is "no match"..

am i missing something obvious here? obviously It did not match any other stuff.. so just made both the regex and the variable to be checked equal.. still no match.

I have tried doing  this too..

```
 if($var =~ $regex ){
```

based on some search from perlMonks.

Comment: Looks like someone rather jumped the gun on closing this as a duplicate. This question has no connection with [the one it was marked as a duplicate of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365906/detect-exact-string-value-of-scalar-in-regex-matching). That was about regexes that include metacharacters that need to be matched literally. The problem here is a complete misunderstanding of regex metacharacters. Please be more careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am i missing something obvious here?

You're missing how regular expressions work. They don't work how shell filename expansion works.

Your regex uses `*` which means "zero of more of the preceding character". So `M*` matches nothing, 'M', 'MM', 'MMM', etc.

You wanted to match "PM" followed by any number of any character followed by "C". The correct regex for that is `PM.*C`. A dot (`.`) means "match (almost) any character" and (as I said above) `*` matches zero or more of that.

I recommend reading the [Perl Regular Expression tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).