# Regex matching with scalars in Perl.

Tags: regex, perl

To the moderators... READ THE QUESTION before marking as a duplicate.

I am using regular expression using scalars here. First time though. I will put the code. It should be self evident

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $regex = "PM*C";
my $var = "PM_MY_CALC";

 if($var =~ m/$regex/){
    print "match \n";
 }

 else{

    print "no match\n";
 }
```

The output that I get is "no match"..

am i missing something obvious here? obviously It did not match any other stuff.. so just made both the regex and the variable to be checked equal.. still no match.

I have tried doing  this too..

```
 if($var =~ $regex ){
```

based on some search from perlMonks.

and if you still think it is duplicate and wants to go to this question right here...

[Detect exact string value of scalar in regex matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365906/detect-exact-string-value-of-scalar-in-regex-matching)

please save your time and ego.. It is not the one, and it does not answer my query.. and please spare some time for this question till someone who genuinely wants to help answers this..

Comment: Your regex is wrong. `"PM*C"` matches a literal P, followed by 0-n letters M, followed by a C. So it would match `PC`, `PMC`, `PMMC`, `PMMMMMC` etc.

Comment: @PerlDuck thanks for that.. could you help me correct it?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with using scalars. `"PM_MY_CALC" =~ /PM*C/` doesn't match either.

Comment: @PerlDuck Already retracted. I do think OP did a less-than-optimal job describing what the actual problem is and why exactly the linked question is not a duplicate.

Comment: @ArunMKumar A genuinuly well-meant comment -- please read up on basics. You got tripped by what `*` means in a regex. The whole topic is tricky, one _has to_ go through basics first.

Comment: @zdim thanks I will...

Comment: All your "READ THE QUESTION" and "please save your time and ego" comments aren't really going to encourage people to answer your question. You might consider removing those.

Comment: hi @DaveCross Common sense dictates that what you say is the right thing to do... but surprisingly this is my second post, When I asked the question, It got marked as duplicate within 10-20 Seconds. IDK how on earth someone can analyze it that fast..  but look here, I have the answer and have such good fellows helping me with it.. Not the most polite way to ask question but hey.. it worked...

Comment: Not a regular at SO , could not find my answer anywhere so used SO as my last resort, but that is a different topic altogether as to why I don't visit stackoverflow.. and why everyone else is better..

Comment: @ArunMKumar: I agree that your previous question shouldn't have need closed as a duplicate. I've reopened it and left a comment saying that.

Comment: Thanks.. @DaveCross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` is a quantifier, not a wildcard in Perl regexes. `PM*C` as a regex means `P`, followed by zero or more `M`s, followed by `C`. For example, the following strings match it:

```
PC
PMC
PMMC
PMMMC
xxxPCxxx
```

If you need to match "anything", use `.*`.

Comment: If you need to match "really anything", also add the `/s` flag. :-)

Comment: cool, thanks guys.. One question here.. your solution returns true even if i do var as "PMC_MY_CALC_IS_FINE" .  I want the regex to match till the end of the string.. how do i do that?

Comment: @ArunMKumar [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) (look for "anchor").

Comment: already did.. tried  "s/PM.*C//" then tried adding the anchor  s/PM.*C$//

Comment: ^ and $ are the anchors I know of in perl regex.. but  using /PM.*C$/ gives a match for PM_MY_CALC_IS_FINE ... Little confused here, New to perl scripting, had some BASH stuff stuck in.. still If you guys can help.. that wud be cool

Comment: @ArunMKumar: I'm not getting 1 from `perl -lwe 'print "PM_MY_CALC_IS_FINE" =~ /PM.*C$/'`

Comment: @ArunMKumar: Also note that `$` has a special meaning in double quotes, switch to single quotes `$regex = 'PM.*C$'` or backslash it `$regex = "PM.*C\$"`.

Comment: my $regex = '/PM.*C$/';       my $var = "PM_MY_CALC_IS_FINEC";    and now .....  if($var =~ $regex) gives a false... regardless of whether the string being tested ends with the character C or not.

Comment: `my $regex = '/PM.*C$/'` is putting literal `/` characters in your regex. That's not what you want at all. You want `my $regex = 'PM.*C$'; ... if ($var =~ /$regex/)`

Comment: @ArunMKumar: I know it works. The important question is - do you understand why it works and your previous code doesn't?